# Variable define bug

Tags: python

I am having a issue running this code. Here is the error I am receiving

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Windows\System32\python
>   test 1.py", line 53, in  counter_c + 1
>
> NameError: name
>   'counter_c' is not defined

I think that the python is interpreting this as a string or a boolean. Does anyone have advice?

Here is my code:

```
while (True == end_command):

    c_l_i = input(">>: ")

    for mlist in master_list:

        inList = ['help', 'other_help']

        if (c_l_i in eval (mlist)):

            counter_c = 0

            inList[0] = "true"

            counter_c + 1

            print (inList)

            #find_in(c_l_i)

        else:

            inList[0] = "false"

            counter_c + 1

            print (inList)

print (inList)
```

Comment: no, python is acting correctly - you are defining `count_c` in your if-clause, but accessing it in your else clause

Comment: @UnholySheep good eyes ... as an aside `count_c + 1` really doesnt do anything ...

Comment: Also, "counter_c + 1" is an expression, not a command.  I think you will need "counter_c += 1"

Comment: Totally unrelated, but there are __very__ few legitimate reasons to use `eval()` in Python.

Comment: How can I do better brunodesthuilliers?